Why do we use present continuous with future tense?
In You will reach there and will see that people are now queuing for tickets. we didn't use the future continuous tense in the place of the present continuous tense.
In The queue will have formed and people will be actively waiting in line by the time you reach there. we used the future continuous tense.
Why?

"By the time." You tied these actions to a time in the future. You might use it similarly with "At 8:00 tomorrow, .... people will be waiting" etc.

@AndyBonner what about the usage of the present tense in a future sentence

Well, while we do that (“The bus leaves at 8”), the example sentence doesn’t make a lot of sense at the moment. Maybe it means something like “you will, in the future, find evidence of what’s happening right now,” but it seems like an unlikely sentence.

The underlying idea is that it will take you some time to get there, and during that time a queue will have formed.

By the time you get there, people will be waiting in line.

"will be" expresses a future situation.
"waiting" expresses an ongoing action.
The line will have already formed before you got there, and those who are waiting in line won't start waiting coincident with your arrival; they were already waiting before you arrived.

By the time we get there in this traffic, the movie will be already playing.

Your first sentence

You will reach there and will see that people are now queuing for tickets.

is idiomatic only if now is understood to have shifted to the future like
The Ghost of Christmas Yet to Come in Dickens.  "now" there would mean "in the present of the future".   It is analogous to the "historical present", just in the opposite time-direction.

You will reach there and will see that people are queuing for tickets. and You will reach there and will see that people will be queuing for tickets I don’t remember a sentence I heard where present tense is used with future tense that’s why I made up these two. Between these two sentences, what’s the difference?

They will be queuing at the time that you see them. Your second version means that, at the time of your arrival, you will see people queuing in the future.

@hwkal Your first sentence, in which you use "now" in a future context, is idiomatic only when you are  treating the future as if it were actually the present. Perhaps you're describing an adventure video game to someone, how its action unfolds:  "You will find yourself in a dense forest but after a while you will come to a clearing where the path forks. Now you decide which way to go."  The word "now" can refer either to the actual present or to an artificial present.  The person describing how the game will unfold is speaking of it as if it were actually happening at that moment.

'Will see' is future simple tense, 'will have formed' is future perfect - meaning at that point in time a completed action influences that current situation.
'Will be waiting' is future continuous, telling us of an ongoing situation. There's one more aspect: "They will have been queueing for some time", future perfect continuous for fully completed actions in the time frame.
